# where is my css coming from in my react-redux project

Tags: css, react-redux, structure, styling

I am doing the thinkster react-redux portion of their full stack app tutorial.  All is going well but there is some default styling that was done that stays consistent as I add aspects to the tutorial.  For example, the homepage has a header that is green, however, in the tutorial, this was never set.  I am wondering if maybe it is being generated within the API being used?  If that's the case, where is the best place in my project t override that?  If not, where is all of this styling and where is the best place to start incorporating my own?  Here's the link to the directory of the finished project.  Second is my code.  Its probably not necessary but just in case!  Thanks

[Thinkster.io Official REPO](https://github.com/gothinkster/react-redux-realworld-example-app)

[My Project Repo](https://github.com/rockomatthews/react-projects/tree/master/react-redux-realworld-example-app)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a css file, **App.css** in **src/styles** folder. Add the below code to it

   .container {
   color: black;
   }
2. Import the same in your App.js as
   `import '../styles/App.css';`

You will see the app name color being overwritten instantly.

Comment: awesome.  Thanks Dude.  That did it!